# About how to run and use a package

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed a driver of rotoscan_node for a laser ,beacuse of this package have no .config or .py file , and the launch file cannot find the node , so  i don`t konw how to run  and use it , please give me a suggest ,thanks  a lot

the driver is in this website :
http://wiki.ros.org/rotoscan_node

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198425/about-how-to-run-and-use-a-package/) by [kdsong](https://answers.ros.org/users/20846/kdsong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The repository seems to have [launch files](https://svn-agbkb.informatik.uni-bremen.de/dfki-sks-ros-pkg/trunk/dfki_sks_laser_drivers/rotoscan_node/launch/) and is a C++ based node, so you'll need to compile it.

A bigger issue may be that it is not a catkin package, but is still rosbuild based.

> I have installed a driver of rotoscan_node for a laser [..]

How did you actually 'install it'? It is not enough to check it out, you'll need to build it.

---

Edit: a quick google search lead me to [github.com/mars-uoit/rotoscan_node](https://github.com/mars-uoit/rotoscan_node), which seems to be a catkinized version of the `rotoscan_node` package you linked. Cloning this into your `src/` space and building using `catkin_make` should then work for you.

---

Edit2: also, isn't this a duplicate of [Error about the rotoscan_node driver for the leuze laser scanner](http://answers.ros.org/question/198318/error-about-the-rotoscan_node-driver-for-the-leuze-laser-scanner/)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kdsong](https://answers.ros.org/users/20846/kdsong/) on 2014-11-27**:
thanks , but when i use the  'Edit '  the output  still
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rotoscan_node/rotoscan_node]: can't locate node [rotoscan_node] in package [rotoscan_node]
maybe ,i can try to build it next .

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-27**:
You **need** to build it using `catkin_make`, there is no other way. This is C++, you cannot execute it in any other way.

**Comment by [kdsong](https://answers.ros.org/users/20846/kdsong/) on 2014-11-27**:
I actually  used the catkin_make into my catkin workspace , but it still like this error ,is there any other solutions ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-27**:
And after `catkin_make`, you remembered to do `source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`?

**Comment by [kdsong](https://answers.ros.org/users/20846/kdsong/) on 2014-11-27**:
of cause  i have , maybe , it is not a correct package ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-28**:
Please update your original question with the exact steps (on the command line) you took to create your workspace, download the package, configure and build it.

The catkinized version of the package I linked works fine for me here locally -- *after* compilation and `source`-ing.

**Comment by [kdsong](https://answers.ros.org/users/20846/kdsong/) on 2014-12-02**:
It seems that  when i  installed the rotoscan node, it can be always output catkin_make error ,  if i delete , it will be ok

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-02**:
That is why I asked you to update your question with *how you created your workspace*.

You most likely forgot to install all dependencies. Do you have the [timeutils](https://github.com/mars-uoit/timeutils) package in your `src` space as well?